# how can i solve an error related to builtin.TabError

Tags: python

i am practicing a tutorial code and i am stuck in line 29( print('bhpnet.py -t localhost -p 9999 -l -u=c:\target.exe')) in a function, am not really sure what the problem is. i keep getting a builtins.TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (bhpnet.py, line 29) i have sought for help on google but i am not getting the right response.i have tried seeting my wing IDE to use spaces only, but i am still stuck, as i cannot run the code. i will greatly appreciate any help from anyone who have an insight to what the problem is and can provide me a way on how i can correct it. below is the code...

```
import sys
import socket
import getopt
import threading
import subprocess


# define some global variables
listen                = False
command               = False
upload                = False
execute               = ''
target                = ''
upload_destination    = ''
port                  = 0

def usage():
    print('BHP Net Tool')
    print()
    print('Usage: bhpnet.py -t target_host -p port')
    print('-l --listen                 -listen on [host]:[port] for incoming connectiions')
    print('-e --execute=file_to_run    - execute the given file upon receiving a connection')
    print('-c --command                - initiate a command shell')
    print('-u --upload=destination     - upon receiving connection upload a file and write to [destination]')
    print()
    print()
    print('Examples: ')
    print('bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -c')
    print('bhpnet.py -t localhost -p 9999 -l -u=c:\\target.exe')
    print('bhpnet.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -e=\'cat /etc/passwd''')
    print('''echo 'ABCDEFGHI' | bhpnet.py -t 192.168.11.12 -p 135''')

    sys.exit(0)

def main():
    global listen       
    global port
    global execute
    global command
    global upload_destination
    global target

    if not len(sys.argv[1:1]):
        usage()

    # read the command line options
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'hle:t:p:cu:', ['help','listen','execute','target','port','command','upload'])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print(str(err))
    usage()

    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ('-h','--help'):
            usage()
        elif o in ('-l','--listen'):
            listen = True
        elif o in ('-e', '--execute'):
            execute = a
        elif o in ('-c', '--commandshell'):
            command = True
        elif o in ('-u', '--upload'):
            upload_destination = a
        elif o in ('-t', '--target'):
            target = a
        elif o in ('-p', '--port'):
            port = int(a)
        else:
            assert False,'Unhandled Option'
    # are we going to listen or just send data from stdin?
    if not listen and len(target) and port > 0:

        #read in the buffer from the commandline
        # this will block, so send CTRL-D if not sending input
        #to stdin
        buffer = sys.stdin.read()

        #send data off
        client_sender(buffer)
    #we are going to listen and potentially 
    #upload things, execute commands, and drop a shell back
    #depending on our command line options above

    if listen:
        server_loop()
```

Comment: Sounds like you've mixed tabs and spaces in your source file, meaning some lines are indented with tabs and others with spaces. In Python it doesn't matter which one you use, you just have to be consistent. I'm not super familiar with Wing, but have you tried using the indentation manager to make all of your indents consistent, as discussed [here](https://wingware.com/doc/edit/indentation-manager)?

Comment: thanks very much, i was able to figure it out, i didnt differentiate between the tab and space indentation, and i see why i was getting the error. i really appreciate.